# Is there an easy way to to find the amount of hex digits in a string?

Tags: python

I was doing some homework and the question asked how many amount of hex digits is in this string for a math question
Now I could do the boring way and count every hex digit or I can use the awesome probably already existing function to do it for me using python :)

```
"44789C7FC5C3F5C7C5A51FB697F3C9B28B2CD67FZ"
```

For example in this string is there a function that would tell number of hex digits?
And a function that would tell me the amount of bits?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to filter out any non-hexidecimal digit, get the length of the filtered string and return how many bits are in that resulting string?

Comment: You can use a little generator, `sum(c in '0123456789ABCDEF' for c in test_str)` (because `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` to `0`)

Comment: What does the "amount of bits" mean exactly?

Comment: Are you asking us to go look through the documentation for you to see if there is a *built-in* function that does what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `filter()` to remove all the letters that aren't hex digits. The `string` module contains some handy constants, including a string with all the hex digits. You can then use `len()` and `list()` to find the number of characters that remain:

```py
len(list(filter(lambda x: x in string.hexdigits, data.lower())))
```

You could also use `sum()` and `map()` to map each character to a `True` / `False` value depending on whether the character is a hex digit, then use `sum()` which interprets `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`:

```py
sum(map(lambda x: x in string.hexdigits, data.lower()))
```

---

For example:

```py
import string
data = "44789C7FC5C3F5C7C5A51FB697F3C9B28B2CD67FZ"
print(len(list(filter(lambda x: x in string.hexdigits, data.lower()))))
print(sum(map(lambda x: x in string.hexdigits, data.lower())))
```

outputs:

```py
40
40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> s='agth123AFz04bCD'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[0-9A-Fa-f]',s)
['a', '1', '2', '3', 'A', 'F', '0', '4', 'b', 'C', 'D']
>>> len(re.findall(r'[0-9A-Fa-f]',s))
11
```